# How do I build an Ant TarTask for this tar command?

Tags: ant, tar

tar zcvf Test.tar.gz /var/trac/test /var/svn/test

So far I have:

```
<target name="archive" depends="init">
    <tar compression="gzip" destfile="test.tar.gz">
        <tarfileset dir="/">
            <include name="/var/trac/test" />
        </tarfileset>
        <tarfileset dir="/">
            <include name="/var/trac/svn" />
        </tarfileset>
    </tar>
</target>
```

With debugging on, it always says "No sources found" so I'm a bit perplexed on what to do next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things here that can go wrong:

1. Are `/var/trac/test` and `/var/svn/test` files or directories? Real `tar` would work fine with both; your task - the way it's written right now - would only work with files but not folders.
2. Do you (or, rather, does Ant process) have adequate permissions?
3. `<include>` elements contain [patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns), which are generally **relative** to base dir. You're specifying them as absolute.

I would rewrite the above as:

```
<target name="archive" depends="init">
  <tar compression="gzip" destfile="test.tar.gz">
    <tarfileset dir="/var/trac" prefix="/var/trac">
      <include name="test/**" /> 
      <include name="svn/**" />
    </tarfileset>
  </tar>
</target>
```

`prefix` allows you to [explicitly specify the path](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/tarfileset.html) with which files in Tar archive should begin.

`/**` within `<include>` tells Ant to take all the files from that folder and all its subfolders. If `/var/trac/test` and `/var/svn/test` are indeed files and not folders then you can omit that.

Comment: I had some mistakes in my example task, but with a small amount of finagling (two tarfilesets, one for /var/svn/test and one for /var/trac/test), it worked perfectly. Thanks a ton!